# Exclude specific entity in List component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` framework version 3.2. I am trying to hide one specific document in my `List` of `game` entities. I have tried to accomplish this by using both `filterDefaultValues` and `filter` but with no luck.

The document that I dont want to display in `List` has name 'g.info'. So I tried this:

```
const gameName = 'g.info';

<List filterDefaultValues={{ name: !gameName }} pagination={<ListPagination />} perPage={30} sort={{ field: '_id', order: 'ASC' }} actions={<Actions />} {...props}>
```

But as I said, this does nothing. Any ideas how can I hide this specific document from List?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, when you say "hide", do you mean hiding that field from the table? Or do you mean that you want you `List` to display filtered values?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the filtering to happen at API level or at UI level?

If the API returns all values and you want to hide the records at the UI level, that would mess up your pagination.

If you want the filtering to happen at the API level, then you must figure out how your query parameters will look like for that API call. For example, you could send a query parameter called `filterInfoGame` (=true/false) and the API should know how to handle it and return only the records you want. Then you set `filter={filterInfoGame: true}` on your List. (I'm not sure this is the RESTful way to do it, it's just the first example that came to my mind.)